# Nginx processes start filling CPU

Tags: nginx

NGINX processes start taking all CPU cores and would not purge and free them. Server has been up for a month with the same configuration as today's, and it just started happening from yesterday.

There are no useful informations in neither `nginx logs` nor `php-fpm logs`. How can I investigate the issue and where and what should I start with? Are there any tools which can help me find out why this is occurring?

In the meanwhile, `top` command output is as shown below :

```
top - 19:14:15 up 24 days,  1:19,  1 user,  load average: 6.54, 4.94, 4.59
Tasks: 507 total,   7 running, 500 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 28.8 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 69.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 26394150+total, 17393424 free, 10442672 used, 23610540+buff/cache
KiB Swap: 10239996 total,  9770156 free,   469840 used. 25128828+avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
26532 nginx     20   0   70904  27784   2056 R 100.0  0.0   3:04.93 nginx
26531 nginx     20   0   61236  18032   2048 R 100.0  0.0   2:46.87 nginx
26533 nginx     20   0   76108  32928   2052 R 100.0  0.0   6:28.67 nginx
26530 nginx     20   0   56644  13416   2048 R  99.7  0.0   2:36.53 nginx
26534 nginx     20   0   53988  10852   2036 R  99.7  0.0   2:35.19 nginx
22620 nginx     20   0  540548  52280  26016 S  15.6  0.0   0:44.84 php-fpm
22670 nginx     20   0  534472  46308  26256 S  10.6  0.0   0:42.25 php-fpm
22702 nginx     20   0  534464  44524  24600 S   9.6  0.0   0:48.06 php-fpm
26528 nginx     20   0   63560  20376   2052 S   7.3  0.0   0:14.94 nginx
22718 nginx     20   0  536248  49320  27516 S   6.6  0.0   0:42.21 php-fpm
22725 nginx     20   0  533968  46476  26984 S   6.0  0.0   0:52.16 php-fpm
22611 nginx     20   0  540692  51000  24640 S   5.6  0.0   0:45.97 php-fpm
22632 nginx     20   0  577992  90824  27048 S   5.6  0.0   0:49.12 php-fpm
22717 nginx     20   0  535236  46316  25740 S   5.3  0.0   0:46.48 php-fpm
22665 nginx     20   0  536292  47420  25620 S   4.3  0.0   0:41.54 php-fpm
22780 nginx     20   0  534728  44748  24504 S   4.3  0.0   0:43.51 php-fpm
22726 nginx     20   0  540552  53544  27420 S   3.3  0.0   0:47.28 php-fpm
26527 nginx     20   0   57560  14428   2048 S   3.3  0.0   0:09.23 nginx
22730 nginx     20   0  534976  45912  25304 S   3.0  0.0   0:46.78 php-fpm
22744 nginx     20   0  540544  50932  24808 S   3.0  0.0   0:45.64 php-fpm
22761 nginx     20   0  542832  54460  27928 S   3.0  0.0   0:52.38 php-fpm
22616 nginx     20   0  535276  45788  24788 S   2.6  0.0   0:49.04 php-fpm
22617 nginx     20   0  540748  53516  27132 S   2.6  0.0   0:42.45 php-fpm
22630 nginx     20   0  603580 114140  24844 S   2.6  0.0   0:47.50 php-fpm
```

NGINX configuration:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /dev/null;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 300m;

    open_file_cache_errors   on;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

NGINX Server Block

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate ...;
        ssl_certificate_key ...;

        server_name ...;
        root /...;

        # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg module
        # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
        gzip_static on;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # This matters if you use drush prior to 5.x
        # After 5.x backups are stored outside the Drupal install.
        #location = /backup {
        #        deny all;
        #}

        # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
        location ~* \.(txt|log|psb|vtt|mpl|idx|smi|sub|ass|srt|ssa|sami|pjs)$ {
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }

        #location = /user/196737/content-sound {
        #        return 403;
        #}

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

        # No no for private
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

        # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
        # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
        # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                # You have 2 options here
                # For D7 and above:
                # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
                # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
                # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
                # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
                #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        }

        # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
        # This is for D6
        #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
        # This is for D7 and D8
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to add your Nginx and Nginx server block configurations. If there's no logs, that's tricky...

Comment: @Tim Post has been updated.

Comment: Config looks fine at first glance. You're going to need to give us more information if you want help solving this. Work out why there's nothing in the logs - could it be high usage or a DDOS (access logs)? Does it go away when service is restarted? If you put a CDN in front of the server and block everyone other than you and the CDN using IPTables (careful) does it help?

Comment: @Tim its not related to attack. number of connection is not abnormal. could  `starce` output help?

Comment: No idea what that is sorry. Hopefully someone else can help. Run every tool you can find that might give you information - atop is one.

Comment: @Tim, it was a bug in nginx 1.11.11. http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES `Bugfix: nginx might hog CPU; the bug had appeared in 1.11.11.`

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. Suggest you answer your own question as it might help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in nginx 1.11.11. http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

> Bugfix: nginx might hog CPU; the bug had appeared in 1.11.11.